# Facet-like contextual filters on View

Tags: 7, views, search

I've created an overview to display jobs. All jobs are tagged with taxonomies "location" and "industry".

I'd like to display contextual filters (with checkboxes) in a sidebar to filter the jobs. As in a facet search. I would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to mimic the behaviour of Facets (with checkboxes) using [the Better exposed filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters).

"The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single- or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively."

If that doesn't help you I suggest just using [Search Api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) with [Search Api DB](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db) and [Facets API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets) to make your filtered view.